# Oracle sql format max number 99999999999

Tags: sql, oracle

Is the number 9999999999999999999999999999 can be written better?
I have multiple queries with that value.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "INVOICES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Comment: [NOMAXVALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571)

Specify NOMAXVALUE to indicate a maximum value of 1028-1 for an ascending sequence or -1 for a descending sequence. This is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need to write out the maxvalue. Use NOMAXVALUE, which caps at the 28-digit number.

You could also replace MINVALUE 1 with NOMINVALUE.

[ORACLE DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314):

> NOMAXVALUE   Specify NOMAXVALUE to indicate a maximum value of 10 27th power
> for an ascending sequence or -1 for a descending sequence. This is the
> default.
>
> NOMINVALUE   Specify NOMINVALUE to indicate a minimum value of 1 for
> an ascending sequence or -10 26th power for a descending sequence. This is the
> default.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "invoices_seq" NOMINVALUE NOMAXVALUE INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to specify only non-default settings.

All of those values except the starting value are the defaults and therefore don't need to be stated (and in my view shouldn't be), so the same sequence can be created more concisely using

```
create sequence invoices_seq start with 21;
```

For the more general case in your question title, 9999999999999999999999999999 is 1e28 - 1.